# Constant interpolation with Noise Modifier

Tags: graph-editor, interpolation

I am trying to create a curve in the graph editor with my interpolation set to `constant` and a `noise` modifier added.

The `noise` modifier seems to only generate curved lines. I need them to be `constant`. I want 0 interpolation between the points, is this possible?

I am trying to generate a random transform over a period of time for an object. But i need it to be `constant`, no interpolation between the transforms. Maybe there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Consider [baking](https://imgur.com/a/GnWNI) the noise with the respective step size, then set the resulting keys to constant.

Comment: @Leander Can you add this as an answer with more detail. I will try it and give a point if it works too.

Comment: @Not necessary, Rich's answer is better and simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you desire by using an additional modifier after the noise - a Stepped modifier.

[image: stepped modifier]

The Noise modifier generates the 'smooth' noise while the Stepped modifier breaks the curve into distinct bands (Step Size) and keeps the value at the same value for the duration of that band.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. ty